# Jinja2: sort text lines in alphabetical order in .j2 template?

Tags: sorting, templates, ansible, jinja2, alphabetical

Is there a way, in a .j2 file to be processed by the Ansible 'template' module, to sort a specific number of lines in alphabetical order? Ideally, the resolution of other Jinja2 blocks/variables inside the sorting block should be resolved first.

Instinctively, I'd like to do that:

```
First part of the file
{% sort_alphabetically %}
Hello, this is line 1
Actually, this second line should be first
{{ line_name }} - what about me?
{% finish_sorting %}
2nd "unsorted" part of the text file
```

Assuming the value of `{{ line_name }}` is `B line`, the output of the template should be:

```
First part of the file
Actually, this second line should be first
B line - what about me?
Hello, this is line 1
2nd "unsorted" part of the text file
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Create a first `to_sort.j2` template:

```
Hello, this is line 1
Actually, this second line should be first
{{ line_name }} - what about me?
```

Set the value of `line_name` anywhere it's relevant.

Then in `final.j2` template:

```
First part of the file
{{ lookup('template', 'to_sort.j2').splitlines() | list | sort | join('\n') }}
2nd "unsorted" part of the text file
```

And finally in your playbook:

```yaml
- name: copy my final template
  template:
    src: final.j2
    dest: /path/on/target/final.txt
```

Alternatively you can set the lines to be sorted in a multiline variable that you will split as above or in a list your can directly sort. As an example, you can change the template to:

```
First part of the file
{{ my_lines_to_sort.splitlines() | list | sort | join('\n') }}
2nd "unsorted" part of the text file
```

and the relevant task to:

```yaml
- name: copy my final template
  vars:
    my_lines_to_sort: |-
      Hello, this is line 1
      Actually, this second line should be first
      {{ line_name }} - what about me?
  template:
    src: final.j2
    dest: /path/on/target/final.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a way to do it indeed. However I was really hoping to use only one file. Could I declare a multi-line variable inside the template and use it in place of 'to_sort.j2' ?

Comment: `Alternatively you can set the lines to be sorted in a multiline variable that you will split as above or in a list your can directly sort.`  You can set that in your template or outside e.g. in  a var in your task.

Comment: Any way to declare a multi-string variable with `{% set MyLines = '{{ nested_variable }}' %}` and get `nested_variable` resolved before the `.splitlines()`?

Comment: ?!? => `{{ nested_variable.splitlines() | list | sort | join('\n') }}` ? Or am I just not getting at all what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Added an example if this is more explicit.